# GWT: Relation Between AbstractActivity and AcceptsOneWidget?

Tags: java, gwt

If you create an `AbstractActivity` subclass then you have to define the following method:

```
@Override
public void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus) {
    // ...
}
```

Does this mean that the same `AbstractActivity` can be "started" with different display regions? Can someone provide a concrete example of how this would happen, from a user experience (UX) perspective?

In other words, if I can say `someActivity.start(displayRegion1, eventBus)`, or `someActivity.start(displayRegion2, eventBus)`, then to me this implies that either:

1. An *activity* is not necessarily associated to a particular *location* on the screen, and thus can be used to process (**in which case, what does it actually do?**) a display region (`AcceptsOneWidget` impl) from any part of the screen; or
2. An activity *is* associated with a particular location, but is more or less a "viewer" type construct that is capable of being passed any display region and displaying its contents.

Can someone please explain this relation to me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity doesn't (shouldn't) rely on *where* it's displayed, so it's passed an `AcceptsOnWidget` that represents that *display region* and it should set itself (or its view or whatever) as the widget for that *display region*.

Where the activity will be displayed (i.e. the value of the `AcceptsOneWidget` argument) is defined with `setDisplay` on the `ActivityManager`:

1. an `ActivityManager` *controls* a *display region*
2. it asks its `ActivityMapper` for the activity for a given `Place`
3. it `start`s this activity giving passing it the *display region* as argument
4. the activity *displays itself* in that *display region* when it's ready.